# Perl Threads: How does Sleep() behave

Tags: multithreading, perl, sleep, thread-sleep

I have the following Perl Script that creates 10 threads and and calls a function 1000 times. In this function there is just a print (for debugging) and `sleep(5)`

Here is the Perl Script:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

my $fetch_q   = Thread::Queue->new();
sub fetch {
    while ( my $num = $fetch_q->dequeue() ) { 
        print "$num\n";
        sleep(5);
    }
}

my @workers = map { threads->create( \&fetch ) } 1 .. 10;
$fetch_q->enqueue( 1 .. 1000 );
$fetch_q->end();
foreach my $thr (@workers) {$thr->join();}
```

When I call `sleep(5)` it seems like the entire program comes to a halt (is this correct?). Also how would I make an individual thread sleep?

Comment: I meant the latter. From my testing it looks like the entire program halts for 5 seconds, so I want to find out how to make an individual thread sleep/halt for 5 seconds.

Comment: Since all your threads call `sleep`, how could you tell the difference with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *When I call `sleep(5)` it seems like the entire program comes to a halt (is this correct?).*

Are you saying you only see one number every 5 seconds? I see 10 numbers every 5 seconds, meaning `sleep` only puts the current thread to sleep.

You can see it more clearly using the following program:

```
use threads;

async {
   print "Before sleep\n";
   sleep 5;
   print "After sleep\n";
};

async {
   for (1..6) {
      print "Boop\n";
      sleep 1;
   }
};

$_->join for threads->list;
```

Output:

```
Before sleep
Boop
Boop
Boop
Boop
Boop
After sleep
Boop
```

> *Also how would I make an individual thread sleep?*

There are ways to achieve this without using `sleep`, but I think you're wrong about `sleep` not doing exactly this.

Comment: Then how would I make entire program halt for `x` seconds

Comment: You can't directly. Each thread executes independently of the others. Each thread would have to coordinate with each other. All activity wouldn't stop instantaneously; how fast depends on how often the threads check the the "snooze instruction".